# How do I reshape a data.frame to long format with multiple value cols using regex expression

Tags: r, tidyr

How do I reshape the data.frame `input` to `result`? Basically the first part of the column name before `"dosis"` should be the new variable with two value columns `value` and `dosis` containing the data of the columns ending with/without `"dosis"`.

This should not be too difficult, but I have difficulties finding the correct regex to use with `pivot_longer` or `melt.data.table`.

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

input <-
  tribble(
    ~"abc", ~"abcdosis", ~"def", ~"defdosis", ~"ghi", ~"ghidosis",
    1, 0, 9, NA, 1, 2
  )

result  <-
  tribble(
    ~"variable", ~"value", ~"dosis",
    "abc", 1, 0,
    "def", 9, NA,
    "ghi", 1, 2
  )

# Not working
pivot_longer(input, 
             everything(), 
             names_to = c("variable", "dosis"),
             names_pattern = "(^dosis)?(dosis)")

# Also not working
melt.data.table(as.data.table(input), measure.vars = patterns("^(?!.*dosis).*$", "dosis$"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr::rename_with()` you can paste `"value"` onto the end of of the non-`"dosis"` columns, then use then use the `".value"` sentinel in `pivot_longer()`. Of course, may have to be more specific with the columns in `rename_with()` if you data is more complex.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input %>%
  rename_with(~paste0(., "value"), -ends_with("dosis")) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c("variable", ".value"), names_pattern = "(.*?)(value|dosis)$")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  variable value dosis
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 abc          1     0
2 def          9    NA
3 ghi          1     2
```